# Need to display a huge amount of multi-row data quickly (lazily) in Qt

Tags: pyqt5, qt5, pyqt6

I have a usecase where I am going to be displaying extremely large text files (10 million lines+).

The files are made up of rows in the model that are between 1 and 20 lines each (mostly 1-2 lines each). I would like the QListView to *mostly* use the "UniformItemSizes" logic when it comes to the scrollbar display and most calculations, but of course for actually painting the display we need lazy evaluation and only pulling the data from the model that is strictly needed for displaying the current screen.

What do I need to implement to do this reasonably easily? I've attached what I consider to be a minimal testcase for this sort of problem (if trying at home, you may want to reduce the rowCount to `100000` or so). When tried, with or without the setUniformItemSizes boolean set, there are long setup delays. Although this case is regular, the actual data doesn't have the consistent pattern of a bastardized fizzbuzz.

```py
from PyQt6 import QtGui,QtWidgets,QtCore
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    class TestModel(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super(TestModel, self).__init__(parent)
        def rowCount(self, parent):
            return 10000000
        def data(self, index, role):
            if role == QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
                row = index.row()
                if (row//10)*10 == row:
                    return 'fizz\nbuzz'
                return 'test1: ' + str(row)
            return None
            
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    model = TestModel()
    view = QtWidgets.QListView()
    #view.setLayoutMode(QtWidgets.QListView.LayoutMode.Batched) # displays widget, but we still have to wait for even the first screen of data
    view.setModel(model)
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: QAbstractItemModel provides the [`canFetchMore()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#canFetchMore) and [`fetchMore()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#fetchMore) functions that actually return an "arbitrary" item count until the view asks for more (normally, by using the scroll bars). The model could even use threading or a basic QTimer to allow lazy loading. Still, showing such an amount of data is probably not a good idea with standard item views, not to mention the fact that scrolling would be a complete nightmare from the UX perspective.

Comment: Unfortunately, one UI requirement here is that the interface starts displaying at around the 90% location in the file.  (The application is a log viewer for a massive custom log system)  I'm likely looking at a custom display widget.

Comment: @jkerian Why is it necessary to show *all the lines at once*? A paged view (with a reasonable maximum display count) would serve just as well, and would seem much more user-friendly.

Comment: I think perhaps I did not explain this well. We are certainly not displaying all the lines at once. We do need to display approximately one page worth of data... that shows up at around the 90% mark, essentially instantly, as well as accurately displaying the scrollbar to give users a feel for where they are in the file.  The more I look at this, the less capable the QListView system seems to be at handling the illusion I need it to present... and a custom widget seems necessary.

Comment: @jkerian while Qt item views have also been developed for scalability, allowing the display of *large* models, they were not developed for **huge** models or models that show huge amount of data within each item (with "huge" meaning in the order of *millions*). Maybe you should consider the [graphics view framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html), which is optimized for large areas/item count and also has some level of content caching; alternatively, you can consider using a QAbstractScrollArea subclass, with limited and optimized QPixmap caching to show the contents.